# Volume buttons on iOS in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to use volume buttons in ion to perform some action in Xamarin forms. I have used the dependency service. It gets initiated but nothing happens when I press the buttons.

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(VolumeButtonService))]

namespace AVAT.iOS.Service
{
public class VolumeButtonService : IVolumeButtonService
{
private readonly AVAudioSession _audioSession;

```
    public event EventHandler<int> VolumeButtonPressed;

    public VolumeButtonService()
    {
        _audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
        _audioSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback);
        _audioSession.SetActive(true);

        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"), OnSystemVolumeChanged);
    }

    private void OnSystemVolumeChanged(NSNotification notification)
    {
        var volume = (int)(_audioSession.OutputVolume * 100);

        VolumeButtonPressed?.Invoke(this, volume);
    }
}
```

}

IN Xamarin forms

in constructor
SubscribeToVolumeButton();

```
    private void SubscribeToVolumeButton()
    {
        var volumeButtonService = DependencyService.Get<IVolumeButtonService>();

        if (volumeButtonService != null)
        {
            volumeButtonService.VolumeButtonPressed += OnVolumeButtonPressed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "nothing happens" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Have you debugged it?  Is your event handler assigned?  Does it get called?  Are there any exceptions or errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS15 or above the "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification" is not being called. Instead you could try Key Value observing method.

This my code for VolumeButtonService.cs for iOS project:

```
public class VolumeButtonService : NSObject,IVolumeButtonService
{
    private AVAudioSession _audioSession;

    public event EventHandler<int> VolumeButtonPressed;

    public VolumeButtonService()
    {
        _audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
        _audioSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback);
        _audioSession.SetActive(true);
        _audioSession.AddObserver(this, new NSString("outputVolume"), NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, IntPtr.Zero);          
    }
    //when system volume change, this will trigger
    public override void ObserveValue(NSString keyPath, NSObject ofObject, NSDictionary change, IntPtr context)
    {
        var volume = (int)(_audioSession.OutputVolume * 100);
        VolumeButtonPressed?.Invoke(this, volume);          
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.